# Can Jackson builder based deserialization set the JsonLocation on a builder method?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to use something like Jackson's `@JsonDeserialize(builder = Foo.Builder.class)` annotation to automatically deserialize an object using a builder. This works great, but the class I want to build also needs to contain the source location of where it was defined in the document that was parsed. However, the source location is not part of the JSON document itself, but rather based on the location of the JsonParser when deserializing the object.

Basically I want Jackson to automatically invoke a setter method on the builder, say `sourceLocation(JsonLocation location)`, passing in the starting [JsonLocation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonLocation.html?is-external=true) of the parser.

Is there a simple way to achieve this, or do I need to copy and modify [BuilderBasedDeserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/BuilderBasedDeserializer.html) to make this work?